# NCover on 64-bit system

Tags: .net, 64-bit, code-coverage, ncover

What do you suggest to use for code coverage on 64-bit environment. It seems that NCover supports 64-bit only in Enterprise version which seems to be quite expensive. Or isn't it? What are people using on 64-bit systems for .NET code coverage?

EDIT: I am aware of the CorFlag workaround. I would like to know what others are doing/using. Are you using something else or are you using NCover (free edition) with CorFlag trick?

Comment: FYI: OpenCover (started 3 years after this question) supports 32 and 64 bit processes on .NET2 and .NET4 platforms (including Silverlight), with branch and sequence coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a nice solution. [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) from [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/) works well and integrates with [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/) and [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Thanks all for their answers.

Answer (score 3):

Google found me this: http://rabdullin.com/how-to-run-free-ncover-on-a-64-bit-machine/

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this workaround. I was more trying to find out whether people are using this workaround or something else. But thank you very much for the link. Finally I have a reference I can give to others. :-)

Comment: Link seems to be broken. Use this one instead: http://rabdullin.com/journal/2008/6/6/how-to-run-free-ncover-on-a-64-bit-machine.html

Answer (score 0):

David, I recently took a look at the open source [Part Cover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/). It too has issues with 64 bit, the [work around](http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?thread_id=1981722&forum_id=605221) also being corflag, provided by a Sharp Develop contributor, who package and integrate with Part Cover.

The snk file is in in their [SVN repo](http://partcover.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/partcover/).

Is NCover Enterprise worth it? I guess only you can really make that decision. There is a 21 day trial. If you can't justify the outlay Part Cover could help you.

It appears that all .NET code coverage tools use c++ packaged as COM. Unless somebody can come up with a managed code implementation, I suspect a 64 bit build will always be required.

Answer (score 0):

What about .Net Coverage Validator? It works with all version of .Net and works with both 32 bit and 64 bit versions. http://www.softwareverify.com/dotNet/coverage/index.html

A managed implementation of a code profiler is not possible (same for Java as well) as then the profiler would instrument itself. Thus all .Net/Java profilers are native unmanaged code written in whatever language you want (although typically C or C++).

Answer (score 0):

Both the Classic and Complete versions of NCover support 64 bit.

Thank you,

Joe Feser

Answer (score 0):

See [SD C# Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CSharpTestCoverage.html) for a tool that handls 32 bit and 64 bit versions of C# with aplomb.